# Cassandra 3.9 CQL tracing bottleneck identification

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cql3

I am using 3 node RF3 Cassandra cluster on AWS.
I set a timeout of a read request for 10ms. I have noticed some of my requests are timing out. This is what I observe in CQL with TRACING ON;

```
Tracing session: 9fc1d420-9829-11e6-b04a-834837c1747b

 activity                                                                                                          | timestamp                  | source        | source_elapsed | client
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                                Execute CQL3 query | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.274000 | 10.20.30.40 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
        Parsing select * from recipes where id = fcc7d8b5-46d3-4867-903c-4a5c66a1fd2e; [Native-Transport-Requests-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.274000 | 10.20.30.40 |            264 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                 Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.274000 | 10.20.30.40 |            367 | 127.0.0.1
                                                        reading data from /10.20.0.1 [Native-Transport-Requests-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.275000 | 10.20.30.40 |            680 | 127.0.0.1
                                         Sending READ message to /10.20.0.1 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.20.0.1] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.286000 | 10.20.30.40 |          12080 | 127.0.0.1
                                  READ message received from /10.20.30.40 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.20.30.40] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.296000 |  10.20.0.1 |             51 | 127.0.0.1
                                                         Executing single-partition query on recipes [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2423 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2481 | 127.0.0.1
                           Skipped 0/4 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2548 | 127.0.0.1
                                                             Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 55 [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2614 | 127.0.0.1
                                                            Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 130 [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2655 | 127.0.0.1
                                                            Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 140 [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2704 | 127.0.0.1
                                                            Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 141 [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298001 |  10.20.0.1 |           2739 | 127.0.0.1
                                                           Merged data from memtables and 4 sstables [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298001 |  10.20.0.1 |           2796 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                   Read 0 live and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.298001 |  10.20.0.1 |           2854 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                  Enqueuing response to /10.20.30.40 [ReadStage-8] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.299000 |  10.20.0.1 |           2910 | 127.0.0.1
                         Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /10.20.30.40 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.20.30.40] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.302000 |  10.20.0.1 |           6045 | 127.0.0.1
                          REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /10.20.0.1 [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.20.0.1] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.322000 | 10.20.30.40 |          47911 | 127.0.0.1
                                                     Processing response from /10.20.0.1 [RequestResponseStage-42] | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.322000 | 10.20.30.40 |          48056 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                  Request complete | 2016-10-22 10:32:02.323239 | 10.20.30.40 |          49239 | 127.0.0.1
```

While looking at [DataStax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html) it seems that source_elapsed column is elapsed time in microseconds before the event occurred on the source node.

There is a big time gap between Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /10.20.30.40 and REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /10.20.0.1.

Does this indicate a network latency issue?

Comment: How many of your requests (in percents) time out?

Comment: Percentage is nearly 5% (4.5454% to be precise)

Comment: I would recommend you to monitor the situation with different samples and timeouts.hope the nodes are located on the same zone. the time difference is also based on the nature of the query. so, i would recommend you to monitor a particular query in various in time intervals with different timeout periods.